# Go lang compiler causes (unknown) error with ldflags

Tags: go, pagefile, ldflags

I'm trying to compile Syncthing for WD My Cloud Ex2. It's an arm architecture and it works with 64kb pagefile, so while compiling, there must be a flag ("-R 65536").

When compiling I get the following error

```
c:\src\github.com\syncthing\syncthing>go run -ldflags "-R 65536" build.go  -goos
 linux -goarch arm -no-upgrade tar
# command-line-arguments
syscall.errors: .data.VirtualAddress = 0x347000, want 0x350000
```

Unfortunately at Google there aren't any results at all concerning this error message. What can I do about this message?

Comment: are you using an up to date version of Go?